# C++ Look for a value in a text file then load that row into an array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

**Data:**

```
1 2.5 2.4 3.5 4.5
2 3.5 2.2 1.5 3.2
3 4.5 2.1 6.4 2.1
4 6.4 3.2 6.4 1.2
```

e.g I want to load all of the values of row 3 into an array such as

```
row[0] = 3
row[1] = 4.5
row[2] = 2.1
row[3] = 6.4
row[4] = 2.1
```

The code asks the user for a number which chooses the row from a text file full of data, to be put into the array. I would like to know how to interpret from the text file and store the data that has been found in an array for use later.

I hope that makes sense. I could do this in seconds in PHP but it needs to be done in C++ which is why I am posting here. I have very little experience of the syntax of C++ and if it is even possible to do what I am asking.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
The current code... actual array is 12 * 12

```
   int main()
{
    double Wv, Wp, L, bw,  bd, Wt, M, sigmyd, kh,  ksys,  kmod,  fmyk, gamm, fmyd, Vd, fvd, fvk, kv, fc90d, fc90k;
    int Cno, row, col;
    input_data(Wv, Wp, L, bw, bd, Cno);

    double array[12][12];

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("data.txt");

    if (inFile) {

    cout << "Data file found, pulling in the data now...";

    for (col = 0; col <= 12; col++)
        {
            for (row = 0; row <= 12; row++)
            {
                inFile >> array[col][row];
                cout << array[col][row]<< endl;
            }
        }

    } else {

    cout << "Data file not found!"<<endl;

    }

    inFile.close();

    Wt=total_load( Wv, Wp, bw, bd);
    M = max_bending_moment(Wt, L);
    sigmyd = Bending_stress(M,bd,bw);
    cout<< "The total load on the beam is "<<Wt<< endl;
    cout<< "the maximum bending moment of the beam is "<<M<<endl;
    cout<< "the Bending stress of the beam is "<<sigmyd<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Similar questions are frequently answered: what is wrong with these? Also, what did you try? There is suspiciously little code in question.

Comment: `if it is even possible to do what I am asking.` ....

Comment: "but it needs to be done in C" - then why do the title and the tags say C++?

Comment: Edited with the code I have so far, not 100% if it is correct, I am struggling with the syntax... Noob error I thought C was an abbreviation of C++!

Comment: Changed edited code, I copied that code from the wrong file accidentally, that was another attempt but it was so wrong I re-did it totally, the edit might make more sense now lol

Comment: is it possible to put a variable into inFile.open("data_c.txt"); to make it go to a different file based on an input?

Comment: You certainly _don't_ want to use `inFile.eof()`! Instead you want to use something along the lines of `while (col < n && inFile >> array[col][row]) { ++col; }`. ... and, yes, you can use a `std::string` variable as the argument to the file (although if you have an older library you may need to use `name.c_str()`).

Comment: I am using Xcode to develop this, I can't get the file to be found when it is in the same working directory... any ideas? I have edited the code again and included it in the original question.

Comment: C++ is a fairly poor choice of language for this.  String processing is not its strong suit, and you will not achieve much better performance here than if you used PHP (or anything else).  Think about whether you really want to do this in C++, because by the looks of things you will end up with bugs, and correct code is the best kind, regardless of the language.